# ROS2 node unable to receive new service calls after first call

Tags: ros, ros2, callback, rosservice

I'm currently working on a node that has a service that calls other services within that service. Something like this:

Node A:

- Service A

1. Calls service B of Node B
2. waits for service B to complete (spin until future complete)
3. Calls service C of Node C after
4. waits for service C to complete
5. returns response

service A is in its own mutually exclusive callback group, and service B and C are in a separate different callback group

Currently these nodes are launched together in a launch file. When I call service A for the first time, it runs to completion as expected, and I receive a response and everything (calling the service in a separate terminal). All my debugging messages indicate that the first service call runs to completion.

However, when I try to call the same service again, nothing happens, it appears as though something is blocking the node from receiving any new service requests. Same thing happens when I try calling other services of Node A after (none of them run). The node doesn't seem to even receive a request as when I put debugging logs at the very start of the callback, they don't get printed.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated, nothing I've tried has worked for me so far.

Code snippets below:

Initializing client (for service B) within Node A:

```
self.platform_actuator_cli = self.node.create_client(
        MoveToPos,
        "/spc_unit_tester/platform_encoded_actuator",
        callback_group=self.node.client_cb_group
    )
    while not self.platform_actuator_cli.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1):
        self.logger.info("Waiting for platform actuator service...")
    self.platform_actuator_req = MoveToPos.Request()
```

Initilizing service A within Node A:

```
self.home_platform_srv = self.node.create_service(
        HomePlatform,
        "home_platform",
        self.home_platform_cb,
        callback_group=self.node.server_cb_group
    )
```

Service A callback (which runs to completion returning response the first time it's called):

```
def home_platform_cb(self, _request, response):
    self.logger.info("Homing platform.")
    self.platform_actuator_req.pos = 0
    self.future = self.platform_actuator_cli.call_async(self.platform_actuator_req)
    rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self.node, self.future)
    response.success = True
    return response
```